# ora 12560 tns protocol adapter error- while connecting to oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I have oracle 9i already installed in my machine. I am trying to connect to the oracle but while connection i am getting "***ora 12560 tns protocol adapter error***" type of error. i have tried it with the default pass scott/tiger , system/manager..

When i tried to connect to the oracle using default credentials i am getting the above error.

is it the problem with the username and password ? if so how can i get the username and password which is already set ?

Answer (score 1):

IME, ORA-12560 means the Oracle Universal Installer messed up your listener configuration.

Assuming you have an Oracle 9i *Server* installed on your computer, here's a list of things to check.

- does "lsnrctl status" show your database instance?
- does "tnsping my_service_name" work?
- do tnsnames.ora and listener.ora contain entries for your database? Are the hostname / port etc. correct?

If the configuration is wrong, your best bet is to start netca, remove your existing listener configuration and re-configure it.

One question, though: Why do you want to run Oracle 9i? Do you have to support some kind of legacy application / database? (Oracle 11gR2 is so much nicer than 9i)

Answer (score 0):

`Start -> Run -> services.msc`

Select the oracle service name and right click on it then select start.